# How do you go from a .csv file to a templated and formatted .docx file in JS?

Tags: javascript, csv, docx

#### Part 1:

I have a word document that is already formatted the way I intend to keep it.
Then I use a .csv file to fill in data in that word document.
How can I write a script in a web app to convert that .csv -> .xml or .xsl or whichever langauge it needs so that I can just use template variables to autofill the word doc?

#### Part 2:

How do I keep the formatting of the word doc consistent?  Can I just use that template file I already have saved or do I need to convert that to a lower level as well?

Comment: What library do you use to parse the .csv file in javascript?

Comment: What library do you use to read/write the .docx file in javascript?

Comment: I haven't used any library or parser yet.  I'm just fed up with entering the data by hand and I was hoping to gain some insight or direction as to which tools/libraries/techniques have helped others with a similar problem and apply those with any other suggestions to hopefully solve that issue.

Comment: Then break your big problem into smaller ones and start solving them. Hiere are some ideas:

- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8493195
- http://papaparse.com
- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25231724