# How to convert base64 string to doc/docx in c#?

Tags: c#, memorystream

I am working on mvc web based project, and want to convert **base64 string** to **doc/docx** file using **c#**..I've idea about converting base64 to image file but don't have doc/docx file,have searched a lot but didn't get any solution. anyone have idea about this...? 
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply create rtf file

Add `system.windows.forms` reference to your project

```
RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();
rtb.Text = "Base64String";
rtb.Save("Path");
```

And about creating **docx** file

Use this [open source project](https://docx.codeplex.com/) for creating **docx** file like this

```
  var doc = DocX.Create("FileName");
  // Insert a paragrpah:
  doc.InsertParagraph("Base64String");
  // Save to the output directory:
 doc.Save();
```

More information :

[How do I create the .docx document with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19656626/how-do-i-create-the-docx-document-with-microsoft-office-interop-word)

[Create and Manipulate Word Documents](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/660478/Csharp-Create-and-Manipulate-Word-Documents-Progra)