# Saving Word doc in Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, document, savefiledialog

I am very new to Vb and I got faced with an issue when saving text from a text box into a word doc. The document saves fine wherever I want it to save but when I open it pops up with
[image]

This is the code for the save

```
Private Sub BtnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnSave.Click
    Dim SaveDialog As New SaveFileDialog
    SaveDialog.Filter = "Word Document (*.docx)|*.docx|Word 97-2003 Document (*.doc)|*.doc|Plain Text (*.txt)|*.txt"
    SaveDialog.ShowDialog()
    If SaveDialog.FileName <> "" Then
        Dim writer As New StreamWriter(SaveDialog.FileName)
        writer.WriteLine(TxtPreviewcertificate.Text)
        writer.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class
If anyone could help me with this please let me know, thanks.

Comment: docx files are not simple text files. Save your file with txt extension

Comment: you could use interop...xml sdk...or other 3rd parties to create word docs...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19656626/how-do-i-create-the-docx-document-with-microsoft-office-interop-word

Answer (score -1):

I changed it from .docx to doc

```
SaveDialog.Filter = "Word Document (*.docx)|*.docx|Word 97-2003 Document (*.doc)|*.doc|Plain Text (*.txt)|*.txt"
```